# Selenium element not interactable error for login button on Discover Card website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to login on the [Discover Card website](https://www.discover.com/). This script will be for automating the download of statements.

However my function, which works for most websites, is not working for the Discover Card login form. My functions find the login button (ID is "`log-in-button`") but Selenium then fails with the error "`element not interactable`."

This is my small function.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

def login_by_id(username, password, username_id, password_id, login_button_id, driver):
    # wait for form to be visible to Selenium
    username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, username_id))

    # fill in form
    username_input.send_keys(username)
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_id(password_id)
    password_input.send_keys(password)

    # click on login button
    login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, login_button_id)))
    login_button.click()
```

Comment: What are the values you have used for `password_id, login_button_id`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two elements on that page with id 'log-in-button'.

If you're trying to interact with the one in the modal while the modal is hidden would result in this type of error.

The code for the modal window occurs prior to the code for the default login box so it makes sense it would find the hidden one first.

[image]

You could try these

```py
(By.XPATH, '//input[@class="btn-primary log-in-button right"]')
#or 
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-primary.log-in-button.right')
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it for me.

I did not except two elements to have the same ID. Thanks for explaining it so well. 

Comment: In THEORY, they shouldn't. In practice I run into that more often than I would like. I even went so far to write a function that double checks the assumption that the ID being looked for is unique on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to login on [the website URL shared by you](https://www.discover.com/)
with the below code, it seems to be working fine  :

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.discover.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userid-content"))).send_keys('some user name')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password-content"))).send_keys('some password')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='content-login-checkbox']+input+input"))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```